# Does objects in vue call for import every time they're created?

Tags: vue.js

I'm still relatively new with vue and I'm not sure if this way to write it would cause performance issue or generally should just be a thing to avoid. I apologize if this is a stupid question.

So,

When you create a vue object, you can import other vue objects to it. 
Now if this parent object was in a "v-for".

```
<div v-for="parent in parent_list" >
    <parent-object />
</div>
```

like so, would the calls for imports inside "parent-object" happen every time the v-for creates a new parent-object?

Comment: no, probably the component will be loaded once and rendered for each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the system is smart enough not to re-import something over and over. Once something is imported it will re-use the same import later on.